# How to read data from multiple qubits and feed it to a MLP

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, quantum-state

Being new in the field of quantum computing, I tried with the implementation of "https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-machine-learning/machine-learning-qiskit-pytorch.html" using a single qubit. Now, in the same problem, how can I read my data from multiple qubits after passing through all gates in the quantum circuit and pass the output to a MLP network. The input[0] in my dataset takes the form:

```
input[0] tensor([[1.4843, 0.0000, 1.7123, 0.0000, 1.5705, 0.0000, 1.7788, 1.6916, 0.0000, 1.0452, 1.6297, 1.6774, 0.0000, 1.6280,
         0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.7399, 1.5088, 1.6695, 0.0000, 1.7284, 1.7700, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
         0.0000, 0.0000, 1.8018, 1.6226, 1.6714, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.7501, 1.5830, 1.6778, 1.7470, 1.7416],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
         0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
         0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
         0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
         0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]],
       requires_grad=True)
```

Also how can I decide that for a given number of features and dataset, how many qubits I should take.
Thanks in adv..